# 連番処理でのブレイク処理で

Tags: perl

出力の5項目目に出力した1項目目＋3項目目が同一の件数をカウントして表示したいです。

各処理の説明。
input.csvを読み込んで、output.txtを出力する。
input.csvの2項目からブレイク処理に応じて3項目目と4項目目を作成。

3項目目は、1から始まり2項目目がブレイクすると+1、1項目目がブレイクすると1にリセット。
ついで、データ連番が10になっても+1カウントします。

4項目目は、1から始まり1項目目が同じなら+1ずつカウントし、ブレイクしたら1にリセット。

入力データ(input.csv)

```
1,A0000001
1,A0000001
1,A0000001
1,B0000001
1,B0000001
2,B0000001
2,B0000002
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
3,C0000001
```

現在の出力(output.txt)

```
001,A0000001,0000001,0000001,001
001,A0000001,0000001,0000002,001
001,A0000001,0000001,0000003,001
001,B0000001,0000002,0000004,002
001,B0000001,0000002,0000005,002
002,B0000001,0000001,0000001,002
002,B0000002,0000002,0000002,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000001,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000002,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000003,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000004,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000005,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000006,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000007,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000008,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000009,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000010,001
003,C0000001,0000002,0000011,001
003,C0000001,0000002,0000012,001
```

出したい出力

```
001,A0000001,0000001,0000001,003
001,A0000001,0000001,0000002,003
001,A0000001,0000001,0000003,003
001,B0000001,0000002,0000004,002
001,B0000001,0000002,0000005,002
002,B0000001,0000001,0000001,001
002,B0000002,0000002,0000002,001
003,C0000001,0000001,0000001,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000002,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000003,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000004,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000005,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000006,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000007,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000008,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000009,010
003,C0000001,0000001,0000010,010
003,C0000001,0000002,0000011,002
003,C0000001,0000002,0000012,002
```

ソースコード

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# デバックプリント
my $debug = 0;
my $debug2 = 0;

# 初期化
my $num = 0;        #処理区分
my $card_num = 0;   #カード契約番号
my $serial_num = 0;     #通数連番
my $serial_data = 1;    #データ連番
my $sheets = 1;     #枚数
my @in1;        #入力データ
my %hash = ();  #入力データ
my $line1 = "";

my $sheets_count = 0;
my $serial_num_count = 0;


# キー
my $inKEY = undef;      #入力キー
my $cardKEY = undef;    #入力キー２
my $serialKEY = undef;

# テスト結果
my $in1_ctr = 0;
my $out1_ctr = 0;

# ファイルオープン
open(IN1, "input.csv") or die ":$!";
open(OUT1, ">output.txt") or die ":$!";

while(my $line1 = <IN1>) {
    chomp($line1);
    @in1 = split(/,/, $line1,-1);
    # キーの設定
    $num = $in1[0];
    $card_num = $in1[1];

    # データ入力件数をカウント
    $in1_ctr++;

    #処理区分が同じ
    if ($inKEY eq $num) {
        $serial_data++;
        print "\n処理区分同じ\n";
        print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
        print "\$num = $num\n";
        print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
        print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";

        #処理区分同じのカード番号ブレイク
        if ($cardKEY ne $card_num) {
            $serial_num++;
            $sheets = $sheets_count;
            $sheets_count = 1;
            print "\n処理区分同じのカード番号ブレイク\n";
            print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
            print "\$num = $num\n";
            print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
            print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";
        }

        #処理区分同じの通数連番同じ
        elsif ( $serialKEY eq $serial_num) {
            $sheets_count++;
            # $sheets = $sheets_count;
            print "\n処理区分同じの通数連番同じ\n";
            print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
            print "\$num = $num\n";
            print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
            print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";
        }

    }
    #処理区分ブレイク
    elsif ($inKEY ne $num) {
        $serial_data = 1;   
        $serial_num = 0;
        $sheets_count = 1; 
        print "\n処理区分ブレイク\n";
        print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
        print "\$num = $num\n";
        print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
        print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";

        #処理区分ブレイクのカード番号ブレイク
        if ($cardKEY ne $card_num) {
            $serial_num++;
            $sheets_count = 1;
            $sheets = 1;
            print "\n処理区分ブレイクのカード番号ブレイク\n";
            print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
            print "\$num = $num\n";
            print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
            print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";
        }

        #処理区分ブレイクのカード契約番号ブレイク
        elsif ($cardKEY eq $card_num) {
            $serial_num = 1;
            $sheets_count = 1;
            print "\n処理区分ブレイクのカード契約番号ブレイク\n";
            print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
            print "\$num = $num\n";
            print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
            print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";
        }

        #処理区分ブレイクの通数連番同じ
        elsif ( $serialKEY eq $serial_num) {
            $sheets_count++;
            $sheets = $sheets_count;
            print "\n処理区分ブレイクの通数連番同じ\n";
            print "\$sheets_count = $sheets_count\n";
            print "\$num = $num\n";
            print "\$card_num = $card_num\n";
            print "\$serial_num = $serial_num\n";
        }
    }

    # データ連番が11以上なら通数連番を+1
    if ($serial_data == 11) {
        $serial_num++;
    }
    &s_out();
}

close(OUT1);
close(IN1);

# 結果表示
printf "入力ファイルの件数：%9d\n", $in1_ctr;
printf "出力ファイルの件数：%9d\n", $out1_ctr;

# 出力時の処理
sub s_out {
    $num = $in1[0];
    $card_num = $in1[1];
    $out1_ctr++;

    my $out1 = sprintf("%03d,%08s,%07d,%07d,%03d", $num, $card_num, $serial_num, $serial_data, $sheets);
    print OUT1 "$out1\n";

    # 出力後のキー
    $inKEY = $in1[0];
    $cardKEY = $in1[1];
    $serialKEY = $sheets_count;
    print "\$inKEY = 出力後：$inKEY\n" if ($debug);
    print "\$cardKEY = 出力後：$cardKEY\n" if ($debug);
    print "\$serialKEY = 出力後：$serialKEY\n" if ($debug);
}
```

Comment: `input.csv` を見せて頂く事は出来ますか？

Comment: input.csvの中身を追加しました。出力ファイルの1項目目と2項目目と同じ内容です。分かる範囲でミスしている変数も修正しました。

Comment: コードから見るに`input.csv` はカンマセパレートですが、提供頂いた物はタブセパレートになっています。

Comment: まずやりたい内容を書いて下さい。input.csv の内容のどの部分をどう集計してどの様に出力したいのか。それがないと現状のコードのどの部分が正しくてどの部分が間違っているのか分かりません。

Comment: やりたりことを書きました。input.csvですが、カンマセパレートです。失礼しました。Excelからそのままコピペしてしまいました。

Comment: 出力結果の違いを見るに、`出したい出力`が`4項目目は、1から始まり1項目目が同じなら+1ずつカウントし、ブレイクしたら1にリセット。`という期待通りの結果になっていない様に見えますがどうでしょうか？

Comment: 期待通り出力できてます。1項目目が001から002にブレイクするとき、4項目目をリセット（１にする）して、カウントしています。002から003にブレイクするときも同様です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

出力の5カラム目は、出力の2カラム目が変更されるまでの個数になるかと思いますので、変更された事を判断して行を戻って値を更新する必要があります。ですので逐次で出力は出来ません。全てメモリに保持する必要があります。

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.csv' or die "failed to open: $!";
my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

# CSV データを読み取る
my @rows;
my @lines = split "\n", $content;
for my $line (@lines) {
  push @rows, [(split /,/, $line), 0, 1, 0];
}

my $prev1 = ""; # 入力1カラム目の前回値
my $prev2 = ""; # 入力2カラム目の前回値
my $last5 = 1;  # 出力カラム5

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@rows); $i++) {
  my $row = $rows[$i];

  # 1行前の値をコピーしておく
  $row->[2] = $rows[$i-1][2] || 0;
  $row->[3] = $rows[$i-1][3] || 0;

  # 出力3カラム目が変更されたかどうかを確認する為に退避しておく
  my $old = $row->[2];

  # 入力1カラム目が違う
  if ($prev1 eq $row->[0]) {
    # 出力4カラム目が10を超えるか
    # 入力2カラム目が違う
    # ので出力3カラム目をインクリメント
    if ($row->[3] % 10 == 0 || $prev2 ne $row->[1]) {
      # 出力3カラム目をインクリメント
      $row->[2]++;
    }

    # 出力4カラム目をインクリメント
    $row->[3]++;
  } else {
    # リセット
    $row->[3] = 1;
    $row->[2] = 1;
  }

  # 出力2カラム目が変更された
  if ($old ne '' && $old ne $row->[2]) {
    # 出力2カラム目が同じであった個数が $last5 に入っているので
    # 行を戻って値が入っていない部分(0)を更新していく
    for (my $j = $i-1; $j >= 0; $j--) {
      last if $rows[$j]->[4] ne 0;
      $rows[$j]->[4] = $last5;
    }
    $last5 = 1;
  } else {
    $last5++;
  }
  $prev1 = $row->[0];
  $prev2 = $row->[1];
}

# 出力2カラム目が同じであった個数が $last5 に入っているので
# 行を戻って値が入っていない部分(0)を更新していく
for (my $j = scalar(@rows)-1; $j >= 0; $j--) {
  last if $rows[$j]->[4] ne 0;
  $rows[$j]->[4] = $last5;
}

# データを表示
for my $row (@rows) {
  print sprintf("%03d,%08s,%07d,%07d,%03d\n",
    $row->[0], $row->[1], $row->[2], $row->[3], $row->[4]);
}
```

Comment: my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };とは何をする動作でしょうか？読み込みファイルのデータでしょうか？

Comment: perl の `$/` は `<$fh>` で読み取る際の区切り文字で、通常はこれが改行コードに設定されています。上記の様に `local $/` する事で区切り文字が無くなり、つまりはファイル全体を読み込む事が出来ます。